# Interact with program by bash means only

Tags: bash, automation

Is it possible to interact with a running program like eg. `expect` or `sshpass` do without having these tools, by bash means only? What are the low level interfaces the user interaction takes place, and are they accessible to bash scripts?

Comment: expect works by creating the user process without an attached terminal.  The "headless" process then reads from stdin which is the expect script.  The "at"  command does this, and is part of linux.  Your sysadmin may have access to the at command turned off.

Answer (score 0):

One way would just be to create the expect script and then call it via your bash script

Comment: I didn't know `expect` is a script either. So maybe it could be used on systems without root access. But it depends on TCL it seems?

Comment: i have a bash script which checks an varibles format, if correct format then it passes to an expect script.. all run without root priblidges   `/usr/bin/expect`

Comment: I meant that root access may be needed to install expect, if it isn't on the machine. But if it's just a script, it may be run from the local folder without beeing installed.